# Accessing the key of a KeyValuePair just returns the string "Key"

Tags: c#, razor, model-view-controller, keyvaluepair

I have a list of KeyValuePairs (string, bool). I am iterating over the list using a for loop, but when I try and access the key of the kvp at the current index, all I get is the string "Key".

The KeyValuePair is {"DD", false}

Sorry if this is super obvious, but I can't find anyone haveing the same issue.

```
{
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Client.PaymentChannels[i].Key)
}
```

I would expect the Key to be the string "DD", and not the string "Key".

Edited: Sorry I pasted in the wrong piece of code.

Comment: I believe the first argument to `CheckBoxFor` is meant to provide the *name* of the check box property, by looking down the expression tree for the final property name. It's not meant to provide the *value* of the checkbox.

Comment: Right you are, sorry I pasted in the wrong part. The checkbox is correctly showing the value part of the kvp

Comment: Right, the point is the same though: `LabelFor` deliberately extracts the property name, which in this case is `Key`. If you just want a label using that value, you can do that without an expression tree at all: `<label>@model.Client.PaymentChannels[i].Key</label>`

Comment: Thanks. That gave me an error to do with model directory, but was otherwise spot on.